# GitHub "Used By" section not working for pypi packages

Tags: python, github, pypi, python-poetry

We have an [open source pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/fal/) and the code is [hosted in Github](https://github.com/fal-ai/fal/), how do I make GitHub recognize this and start reporting in the `Used by` section.

We have a [project using this one](https://github.com/fal-ai/fal_dbt_examples/network/dependencies) and it shows the project with a ghost next to it:

[image: ghost user for project]

I cannot find any concrete documentation on how to achieve this in the GitHub docs.

Comment: Were you able to find anything more on this? From my reading of the docs (https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/understanding-your-software-supply-chain/about-the-dependency-graph#supported-package-ecosystems), there might be certain configurations e.g. setup.cfg, that will not be picked up by dependabot. However, that does not address your specific issue of the `Used by` section missing

Comment: I opened a discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/12101 and they manually fixed it